# How to NPM Install Private Repositories as a Dependency via SSH

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, npm-install, git-bash

Within my organisation on Bitbucket, I have several Private Repositories that I want to include in some of our other repositories. I'm trying to do this via the NPM Dependencies and install via 'npm install'.

I'm using a Windows 10 machine and have the package.json as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-repo": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/org/my-repo.git#master"
  }
```

I have configured the SSH keys on the machine and verified they can connect using ssh -T git@bitbucket.org. I have also added the key as either an Access Key or as my own SSH key for my account (to try both methods separately). Currently, these SSH keys are setup without a passphrase.

When I try to run npm install in both CMD and Powershell, I get a 'Permissions denied (publickey)' error. When I go to clone the repository manually, it works fine, with the same SSH key. This is being done via the OpenSSH Authentication Agent.

When I try it in Gitbash, it works perfectly fine and as expected. That being said, I did have to run the following command as it didn't recognise the OpenSSH Authentication Agent or the keys I added to it:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Is there a reason why CMD and Powershell will not work as expected when it's clear everything is configured correctly and works in some scenarios?

Comment: Same problem here, with yarn v1.22.10. `yarn install` works in Git bash or WSL, but not in Powershell or cmd, although running the git command manually works in those shells as well.